# Create dynamodb tables from cloudformation yaml file locally (docker)

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to create dynamodb tables in a docker container from cloudformation yaml file?

Comment: DynamoDb tables don't live in a container--they are standalone tables in a specific AWS service.  You can create these tables in CloudFormation YAML scripts.

Comment: your not getting what im trying to say sir. I have a running image of dynamodb and we deploy our stuff via cloudformation on aws. what im trying to do is importing the same tables in my dynamodb image so i can use it locally. thx for response tho.